# What is the Islamic interpretation of Jesus?

Tags: tafseer, history, prophet-isa

I read in [an article](http://www.msn.com/en-us/news/us/2016-campaign-a-season-of-discomfort-for-us-muslims/ar-BBoL2o5) that Muslims believe and recognize Jesus as a holy, or at least historical figure. That got me curious, what is the historical significance of Jesus in the Islamic faith? How does it compare to the Christian significance in which Jesus is the literal son of God, and died as a sacrifice to bear the sins of the world?

As a side note, I tried Jesus in the tags and got a synonym "prophet-isa : also "Jesus"". Is there a link there? If it's related, could it be added to the explanation?

Comment: Then did you also check out the [top voted questions](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophet-isa?sort=votes&pageSize=30) under the same tag ?

Answer (score 0):

Prophet Eissa or Jesus is prophet according to Islamic beliefs. Our belief is incomplete without believing in the Prophets of God which include Prophet Eissa. In Islamic belief Prophet Eissa was born to virgin Mary (Mariam) and is the only Prophet to attain Prophethood at birth. In Holy Quran there is chapter by the name Mariam (Virgin Mary) implying the importance of these two people in a muslim's belief. Eissa(Jesus) had the ability to speak while still in the cradle. Grown up Eissa (Jesus) possessed many miracles such as giving sight to the blind and raising the dead from the grave all  at God's will. In spite of all these miracles Eissa was a human as per Islamic belief. Many other Prophets also did posses miraculous powers but all those Prophets were also human. We also believe in the Holy book of Injeel (bible) revealed to Prophet Eissa. 
Also we believe in the return of Prophet Eissa towards the end of the world(Armageddon) and rule the world for around 40 years. 
For more detailed description of Prophet Eissa (Jesus) in Islam requires a more professional and expert response. What I have said is what we are taught in islamic studies. I too am looking forward to an expert opinion about crucification and other details. 
Peace.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus is a prophet of God like all other prophets (Noah , Zachariah , Ibraham , Moses and finally Mohamed )

Jesus is a "man" son of Merriam without a father .

The story is at sourah number 3 starting from verse 35 ... Enjoy .

Imran's wife wanted a son "Mohrara" (Freed : means freed from the religion of Jews) and God Accepted her request Granted her a daughter "Marriam" . Marriam's mother said that she is female and male is not like female (Because Male are tougher and to survive Male has better chance) But God Accepted her for higher purpose (and it happened) a child speaks defending his mother that she didn't commit an adultery and to speaks the word of God (means a prophet chosen by god to deliver his message) and he does miracles Make a shape of bird from mud and breath on it and it flies , Cure ills (So they have hope in God) , give dead people life again (So people can know who really killed them ) tells what people have at home (Lairs are stingy keeps money at their homes while poor starving) .

Till they made a try to kill him but they didn't kill him that was another man looks like him and Isa (Jesus) survived (God took him to sky) .

However the infidels from Jacob progeny (Who are Cursed by the tongue of David) say that :
He is God and they did kill him .

So they simply says :
That Jews killed God

LOL Why I even worship God , Should I worship Jews ???

Comment: welcome to islam SE. i highly suggest you to look our [help](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help) center and take a [tour](http://islam.stackexchange.com/tour)